# How to get live selector results in a jQuery bind?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm working on a bit of code for a project at work, and am kind of stumped on a nuance of jQuery. In the following code, It should look down my list and iterate each text input element with the same general name as the last one, but with one number higher in the name. Instead what it's doing is iterating the name of each text input element with one number higher than the last number that existed when the link was created. So, it should look like a more complicated version of this this:

```
<input name="industry1" /> <a href="#" class="addField"></a> <!-- Clicked twice -->
<input name="industry2" /> <a href="#" class="addField"></a>
<input name="industry3" /> <a href="#" class="addField"></a>
```

...And instead, it looks like this:

```
<input name="industry1" /> <a href="#" class="addField"></a> <!-- Clicked twice -->
<input name="industry2" /> <a href="#" class="addField"></a>
<input name="industry2" /> <a href="#" class="addField"></a>
```

I think the problem is that the line which selects the value to iterate is set when .live binds to the new add link. So, if the link by the first field creates the button by the second field, and the one by the third field, it acts as if there was still only one field because that's how it was when .live bound a function to the "click" event. Is there any way to force the selector to figure out what the real $("form.wizard ul li.industry:last input[type=text]") in the state of the DOM when the element is clicked is, rather than when it is bound to the element?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $("a.addField").live("click", function(event) {
     $(this).parents("li").clone().appendTo($("form.wizard > ul"))
     .children("input[type=text]").val("").attr("name", function() {
      return "industry" + (parseFloat($("form.wizard ul li.industry:last input[type=text]").attr("name").replace("industry", "")) + 1);
     })
     .after(function() {
       if($(this).siblings(".removeField").length == 0) {
        return "<a href='#' class='removeField'>Remove</a>"
       }
     })
     .siblings("label").text("");
     event.preventDefault();
    });
    $("a.removeField").live("click", function(event) {
     $(this).parents("li").remove();
     event.preventDefault();
    });
   });
  </script>


 <form action="#" method="post" class="wizard">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <label>Your company name</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </li>
   <li class="industry">
    <label>Your Industry</label>
    <input type="text" name="industry1" />
    <a href="#" class="addField left">Add</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </form>
```

Comment: I just created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/4APzT/) of your code (just copy and paste) and it just works as it should. Names are created with ascending numbers added. Which jQuery version do you use.

Comment: @topek your example dosen't get higher than industry2... Something with the pareFloast and a string that dosent work together. If you split them up ( http://jsfiddle.net/4APzT/1/ ) it seems to work fine. Out of ideas :(

Comment: Ok @topek example works as long as you dont press the first adds... so strange.. maybe something with it binding the value to the action?

Comment: It is because when you click the first LI, that is the one it copies, so you always append industry1, then always increment it to industry2 - no matter now many times you click the first LI. I say the same thing a little more wordily as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rearranging parts of the [script](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/4APzT/2/), it now seems to work.

The main problem that I identified was, that the fields were appended and immediately selected with `$("form.wizard ul li.industry:last input[type=text]")`. That's why the number was always the clicked element + 1.

Answer (score 1):

You took an LI element with "industry1" and appended a copy of it - now you have two LI elements with "industry1". Then you took the number of the last one ("1"), increment it (to "2") and set the last LI to "industry2".

Then you click the first LI again. It makes a copy of that one and appends it - now you have {LI name='industry1' /}{LI name='industry2' /}{LI name='industry1' /}. Then you take the number of the last one ("1"), increment it (to "2") and set the last LI to "industry2", resulting in your final unexpected result.